# Creating a JS library with IIFE namespacing

Tags: javascript, module, package, namespaces, iife

If we don't want to use ES6 `import` nor any third party libraries (like require.js etc.) nor any package builder, **what is the classical way to pack a library so that the user can use it with what seems to be a library-namespace?**

`index.html` (from the perspective of the user of the library)

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
<script src="canvas.js"></script>
<script>
canvas.setup({"config1": true, "config2": false});    
var mycanvas1 = canvas.get("#mycanvas");
</script>
```

I sometimes see code similar to

```js
// canvas.js
(function (window, something, else) {
    window.canvas.setup = function() { ... }    // how to export functions setup and get?
})(window, ..., ...);
```

**How to do this [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) properly to create this `canvas.js` library example?**

---

Note: with ES6 `import`, we can package this way a library called `canvas.js`:

```js
const canvas = {
    setup: config => { console.log("config"); },
    get: id => { console.log("get"); }
};
export default canvas;
```

and use it a `index.html` this way:

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import canvas from "./canvas.js";
canvas.setup({"config1": true, "config2": false});
var mycanvas1 = canvas.get("#mycanvas");
</script>
```

but in this question here I am curious about the pre-ES6 solution.

Comment: What's exactly the problem with the last one? And why you don't want to use `es6` imports?

Comment: Looks like you want to look at [section four of this guide](https://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/).

Comment: `var window.canvas` will throw an error, you have to do `window.canvas = {}`

Comment: It works because you're passing in `window.myCanvas` (call it something other than `canvas`) OR an empty object to the function and then adding to that object. If you use the same namespacing technique in your following files they will pick up on `window.myCanvas` (because it's global), and you can consistently add to it. @Basj

Comment: "*I am curious about the good old way to do it, before ES6 was introduced*" you mean the hand-rolled modules or what the somewhat standardised module tools produce? Because the hand-rolled modules can vary in shape. Not *greatly* as they achieve the same result but there would not be The One True Way for things like what arguments you feed the IIFE or which library uses what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution seems to be:

```js
// canvas.js
canvas = (function(window) {   // assign the result of the IIFE to a global var to make
                               // it available for the user of the lib
    var internal_variable;     // not accessible to the user of the lib
    var state;                 // this variable will be available to the user of the lib
    function setup(arg) {
        console.log("setup");
    }
    function get(arg) {
        console.log("get");    // + other lines using window object
    }
    return {setup: setup, get: get, state: state}; // important: here we choose what we 
                                                   // export as an object
})(window);
```

Now the user can use the library this way:

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
<script src="canvas.js"></script>   // object canvas is now available
<script>
canvas.setup({"config1": true, "config2": false});
var mycanvas1 = canvas.get("#mycanvas");
console.log(canvas.state);
</script>
```